# Positioning a div between two buttons

Tags: html, css, ipad, button, position

I'm trying to have a remote control with some buttons, and a div with the now playing info between two of them.

but it doesn't work.

[image: it looks like this in FF with ipad settings (this is how i want it)]

[image: but looks like this on an actual ipad..]

as you can see, on an actual ipad, it renders differently, and i don't know how to fix it.

html:

```
<div id="buttons">
<button id="prev" class="control" onmousedown="skip('prev')"></button>
    <div id="info"> gfegrbhthehrerhg</div>
<button id="next" class="control" onmousedown="skip('next')"></button><br />


<button id="rwd" class="control" onmousedown="changeSpeed(-2)"></button>
<button id="stop" class="control" onmousedown="emitCommand('stop')"></button>
<button id="play" class="control" onmousedown="emitCommand('play: loop: true speed: 100')"></button>
<button id="ffwd" class="control" onmousedown="changeSpeed(2)"></button>
```

css:

```
button.control {
    display: inline-block;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background-size: 150px 150px;
    border:0;
    margin: 0.5%;
}

div#info {
    width:300px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 1.1%;
    position: relative;
    top: -58px;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}

button#prev {
    margin-left: 160px;
}

button#rwd {
    margin-left: 160px;
}


#buttons {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

what am I doing wrong? what is the correct way to accomplish this?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post a fiddle to play about with your code? It will probably be a vertical alignment issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

`vertical-align: top;` to `div#info`

And remove the `top: -58px;` from `div#info` too

Here's a link to a working example: [EXAMPLE LINK](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPGmwg)

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple 4x2 grid system:

```css
#buttonsWrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #BC5555;
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
}

.col4{width: 100%; float: left;}
.col3{width: 75%; float: left;}
.col2{width: 50%; float: left;}
.col1{width: 25%; float: left;}
.col1-height{height: 0; padding-bottom: 25%;} /* make 25% width squared */

.row{
  clear: both;
}

#prev, #next, #rwd, #stop, #play, #ffwd{
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #888;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.95,0.95); /* Safari */ /* scale down to 95% */
  transform: scale(0.95,0.95); /* scale down to 95% */
}

#info{
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonsWrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="prev" class="col1 col1-height"></div>
    <div id="info" class="col2 col1-height"></div>
    <div id="next" class="col1 col1-height"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="rwd" class="col1 col1-height"></div>
    <div id="stop" class="col1 col1-height"></div>
    <div id="play" class="col1 col1-height"></div>
    <div id="ffwd" class="col1 col1-height"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i was thinking about putting it in a table, but didn't want to change the markup so much. your idea, while looking nice, would be too much of changing :(